# Estimating the power usage of a contactor

Tags: datasheet, contactor

I'm trying to figure out the energy cost of the Hartland HCC family [datasheet](https://resource.bakerdist.com/is/content/Watscocom/Gemaire/tradepro_tp-con-32440_article_1366804065029_en_ss.pdf) of contactors, in an application where they are pretty much active (contacts closed) 24/7.

I understand that in an AC application, just using P=squared(V)/R doesn't work because of the power factor. In any case, putting the datasheet numbers in that equation would lead to ~80 watts, which doesn't make sense.

Directly using the "sealed VA" rating (5.5-15VA) as watts is more realistic, although I remember enough AC theory to know that VA aren't watts - and it still feels high.

Does this datasheet provide enough information to evaluate the power dissipation? If so, how? If not, what would be a typical energy use for such a contactor ?

Comment: It does not look like it provides the information. They're probably working on the assumption that whatever it is, it is negligible relative to the full rating of the contactor. Are you planning on running the contactor severely underloaded such that you're worried about the loss?

Comment: That assumption would make sense. The application is seasonal, so it could be turned off for months at a time, both to avoid waste and extend life span. But it is installed out of reach, with no dedicated breaker. I'm trying to find the right effort/reward balance... and to learn at the same time.